# jQuery Check for Hidden DIVs then display message

Tags: jquery

I've some code where I'm showing/hiding DIVs based on choices made in 2 select drop downs. This is working great. Now, I'm trying to display a "no results" message when nothing matches the choices.

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Psykopup/hDWAh/)

It's almost working. The problem is that the "no results" message shows when it needs to, but doesn't hide when should. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should always include the relevant code within your question.  This way if the file/page you are linking to ceases to exist, your question will still remain and could be useful to others in the future.

Comment: @Psykopup, you have gotten a lot of reasonable responses and have not upvoted anything or selected an answer. You should consider doing both.

Comment: Goodness @Kristian. I posted this and got an answer within 7 minutes. Then I had to wait 7 minutes to mark the 1st answer I received.

Comment: I forgot about that rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an else statement after checking for no result:

```
        if ($('.item:visible').length === 0) {
            $(".NoResults").html("<p>No events for your selection.</p>");
        }
        else $(".NoResults").html("");
```

Here is your updated jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hDWAh/8/

Comment: Wow! That was quick and easy. Thanks so much gabitzish.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be missing a condition to empty the contents of the NoResults class. I edited the fiddle to be:

```
if ($('.item:visible').length === 0) {
   $(".NoResults").html("<p>No events for your selection.</p>");
 } else { // NEW ELSE CLAUSE
   $(".NoResults").empty();
 }
```

Edit: While this works, I recommend using RepWhoringPeeHaa's solution below using show()/hide() rather than setting the contents directly.

My main argument for that solution is it keeps more content ("No events for your selection.") in the html template, and out of the code. The better you separate your content/code, the easier it will be to update the content in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You could either [set the contents to nothing](http://jsfiddle.net/hDWAh/14/):

```
        if ($('.item:visible').length === 0) {
            $(".NoResults").html("<p>No events for your selection.</p>");
        } else {
            $(".NoResults").html('');
        }
```

Or simply add the text to the `NoResults` element by default and hiding it using CSS by default (`display: none`). [And then toggle to display/hide](http://jsfiddle.net/hDWAh/12/).

```
        if ($('.item:visible').length === 0) {
            $(".NoResults").show();
        } else {
            $(".NoResults").hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('.item:visible').length === 0)
    $(".NoResults").html("<p>No events for your selection.</p>");
else   // <==============
    $(".NoResults").empty(); // <==============
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hDWAh/6/)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to toggle the visibility every time,

http://jsfiddle.net/hDWAh/7/

Answer (score 0):

Becouse the code is runned from top to bottom, start with always hide `noresult` and when it should be showed, just show it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/hDWAh/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.item:visible').length === 0) {
    $(".NoResults").html("<p>No events for your selection.</p>");
}
else{
 $(".NoResults").html("");
}
```